# Byte Count for a Struct not representing correct amount.

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a bitmap loader and the byte count is not working correctly. I am currently using Xcode running a 64 bit unix executable.

The code:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned int DWORD;

typedef struct {
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffbits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

The sizeof function says the BITMAPFILEHEADER struct is 16 Bytes when it should be 14 Bytes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Alignment? The first element s 2 bytes, followed by one that is 4 bytes. You could try __attribute__((packed))

Comment: The compiler will often pad structs with junk to make them align on word boundaries for quick access (one read for the whole value rather than two reads, one for each half).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be because of structure alignment. Here take a look http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/c-structure-alignment-padding/

You can force the compiler not to align the structure by adding the attribute `__attribute__((__packed__))` but as far as I know it only works in gcc.

Here:

```
struct BITMAPFILEHEADER_S{
  WORD bfType;
  DWORD bfSize;
  WORD bfReserved1;
  WORD bfReserved2;
  DWORD bfOffbits;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

typedef BITMAPFILEHEADER_S BITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

Comment: @Jjack if you ever need to do this with Visual C++, you can do `#pragma pack(push, 1)` before the struct definition and then `#pragma pack(pop)` after the definition.

Answer (score 5):

Your conception that it "should be 14" is mistaken. Structs are usually padded to the members' alignment. To achieve efficient packing with correct alignment, you should order the members by size.

Here's how your struct probably ends up in memory:

```
WORD      [2]
*padding* [2]
DWORD     [4] -- align to 4
WORD      [2]
WORD      [2] -- OK, align to 2
DWORD     [4]
```

Even if you rearranged this to `4, 4, 2, 2, 2`, you might still end up with 16 rather than 14 since the struct may get padded to a multiple of the largest member's size.

Comment: Actually the standard defines that the alignment of a struct is governed by its largest member, so in either case the struct **must** be aligned to 4. I think one reason is that otherwise you couldn't guarantee that every member of the struct was correctly aligned in an array (and you obviously can't include padding between array members!).

Comment: @Voo: Good point, I hadn't thought of arrays! I thought that all those `#pragma pack` directives mean that padding is implementation-defined, but it makes sense that correct alignment is mandated by the standard and everything else is an extension. (I think you have no guarantee on the interior padding, though, a conforming platform *could* insert further dead blocks of 4 bytes in the middle if it wanted.)

Comment: Actually after writing that I'm not so sure anymore (especially because of all those implementation specific alignment stuff, so maybe that's also only an addition I confused?) and wanted to look it up - just no time atm. But my major assumption is valid I think: Access to a member must be correctly aligned according to its size; so if we rearrange the members as in your last sentence and specify a `struct x[2]` the first member of the second struct wouldn't be correctly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the struct is padded to accomodate alignment. This is, however, system dependent.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to alignment.

Additional "padding" bytes are often added between structure/class members to ensure that each member aligns on a particular byte boundary. The result of this is that the size of the `struct` can be greater than the sum of the size of it's members.

There are often (non-standard!) compiler extensions that allow you to control the way that `struct's` are padded, but fiddling with the padding is often a space vs time efficiency consideration - selecting a smaller padding multiple might save you some space, but at the cost of less efficient member access...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

By default there's no guarantee how any given compiler is going to align/pack the fields of a struct. There's typically a way to force it, though, for occasions just such as yours.

```
#pragma pack(n)
```

simply sets the new alignment. Reset to the default with

```
#pragma pack()
```

In your case you should use

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of machines pad structs on DWORD boundries. Normally there is a compiler option to allow you to "pack" the structs so that they are byte aligned. The other two bytes are pad bytes. This might be what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

By default, structure members may be aligned to 4 byte boundaries for better performance. Consider using `#pragma pack` if you really want the structure to be 14 bytes (but there may be a performance penalty to this).

Re-ordering the members of the structure might result in better packing.

In your particular case it looks like you are using this struct to read a BMP file - you will probably need to use `#pragma pack(push,1)` before your struct and `#pragma pack(pop)` afterwards to get the correct packed alignment.

See also [problem writing bitmap file header in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681091/problem-writing-bitmap-file-header-in-c).

Comment: `#pragma pack` is a Visual Studio extension, and won't exist for XCode/GCC/Clang

Comment: @Yann - actually pragma pack is available in GCC for exactly that reason - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: Yep, just verified that #pragma pack compiles and works as expected in Xcode using gcc and clang.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode4.2 this works for me

```
#pragma pack(1)
    struct MyStruct {
        uint32_t width;
        uint32_t height;
        uint8_t compression;
        uint8_t interlace;
    };
#pragma pack()
```