# Bitmap file isn't being saved in the right order in memory

Tags: c, bitmap

I have a bitmap image with 24 bpp, 12x12 pixles. when I try to load it to a strust that was built by this page of [Simplified Windows BMP Bitmap File Format Specification](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm) I get 2 errors:

1. 1. the file size size in struct `BITMAPFILEHEADER` is zero when it should be 54, while the reserved2 should be 0 when it's 54.
   2. the bpp in `BITMAPIMAGEHEADER` is never right.
   3. the image size in the same struct is never right.
   4. the file pointer `fileptr` jumps to a random location which reads trash and not the actual data of the bitmap from memory unless I move it back to the head of the file and manually move it again 14 bytes again.
      my question is: how do I fix this ? **is** there a way to fix this ?

.

```
#ifndef LOADBMP
#define LOADBMP

typedef struct BITMAPFILEHEADER //total of 14 bytes
{
    unsigned char bfType[2];
    unsigned long bfSize;
    unsigned short Reserved1;
    unsigned short Reserved2;
    unsigned long bOffBits;
}BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct BITMAPIMAGEHEADER
{
    unsigned long bisize;
    unsigned long widh;
    unsigned long height;
    unsigned short biplanes;
    unsigned short bpp;
    unsigned long compType;
    unsigned long Image_Size;
    unsigned long biXPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned long biYPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned long ClrUsed;
    unsigned long Clrimp;
}BITMAPIMAGEHEADER;

#endif //LOADBMP
```

main:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LOADBMP.h"
#include "ERROR.h"

void main()
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER BFH;
    BITMAPIMAGEHEADER BIH;
    FILE *fileptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\mishe\\Desktop\\BMP.bmp", "rb");
    unsigned char *image;
    fread_s(&BFH, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fileptr);
    rewind(fileptr);
    fseek(fileptr, 14, SEEK_CUR);
    fread_s(&BIH, sizeof(BITMAPIMAGEHEADER), sizeof(BITMAPIMAGEHEADER), 1, fileptr);
}
```

Comment: In C fread only has 4 parameters...Are you sure this runs?  Does this even compile?

Comment: it says right in there in the code. fread_s. **fread_s**. and fread_s gets 5 parameters.

Comment: Yes my mistake - I need glasses LOL....But why use fread_s?  Shouldn't matter I guess...But makes more sense for a simple fread

Comment: Do you know that the BMP is written on the same Endian arrangement as your code?  What is your BYTE alignment or padding set to?

Comment: I don't know, but the parameters like `height` `width` and `bfType` seem to be correct.

Comment: Assuming Endian is the same...(So ignore that)...You really need to know your compilers settings for byte alignment and struct padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you should add `#include <windows.h>` and use `BITMAPFILEHEADER` and `BITMAPINFOHEADER` which are defined `wingdi.h`

If you define your own `BITMAPFILEHEADER` then `sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)` operator is not garanteed to return 14 as expected, because structure can be padded to member alignment.

If you are not compiling on Windows or Windows header files are not available then use compiler specific keywords to turn off structure alignments. See [Byte Count for a Struct not representing correct amount.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154904/4603670)

Alternatively, read 54 bytes as follows (again, that's assuming you are not on a big-endian machine)

```
unsigned char info[54];
fread_s(info, sizeof(info), sizeof(info), 1, fileptr);

unsigned int width = *(unsigned int*)(info + 18);
unsigned int height = *(unsigned int*)(info + 22);
unsigned int bitcount = *(unsigned int*)(info + 28);

printf("%d %d %d\n", width, height, bitcount);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reference and the code snippet.

Comment: @MichaelMorris I don't think that's supported in Visual Studio. VS uses compiler specific directives `#pragma pack(push,2)`